# Two Level Grouping in SQL

Tags: sql

Need Help on this SQL query..

Table has just 3 columns - Name, Check(Yes / No), Post (true /false)

The result gets ordered by *Check* and then further grouped by *Post* value....

Simply - All Records with Check *Yes* and Post *true* first, then those with Check *Yes* and Post *false*. And so on those with Check *No* and Post *true* and at last those with Check *No* and Post *false*

May be Simpler then it sounds but just can't get this one to work :)

Well the actual table schema is larger then this dummy table but we can assume all these columns to be nvarchars

Comment: What query did you tried? Post your query to motivate us to answer.

Comment: Please include the actual table definition in your question.  Answers will depend on the column data types.

Comment: Did you use `group by check, post`?

Comment: Or rather `order by check, post` since it sounds like that's what you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of the question, this seem to be what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM dummyTable
ORDER BY    [Check] DESC,
            [Post]  DESC
```

Will work with BIT and VARCHAR, because T > F AND Y > N.
In case it is VARCHAR with denormalize data, a good idea would be to use

```
ORDER BY UPPER([Check]) DESC,
         UPPER([Post]) DESC
```

to avoid bad result due to case sensitivity (T < f AND Y < n)